# XSLT - Determine if value exists in a node with multiple same named nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Looking to determine if BBB exists within the XML.  I can effectively echo it out as shown below.  How can I effective search the PRODUCT_CODE node(s) to determine if BBB exists or NOT within the group?

**XML:**

```
<ECOMM_VARS>
  <PRODUCT_CODE>AAA</PRODUCT_CODE>
  <PRODUCT_CODE>BBB</PRODUCT_CODE>
  <PRODUCT_CODE>CCC</PRODUCT_CODE>
</ECOMM_VARS>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="PRODUCT_CODE">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for existence is the result of evaluating an XPath predicate expression in an `if` or `choose`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//PRODUCT_CODE[text()='BBB']">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This outputs `true` if any `<PRODUCT_CODE>` node's text equals `'BBB'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate on your matching template.
The following example does only match the first time (indicated by `[1]`) the text of a `<PRODUCT_CODE>` element matches the string `'BBB'`.

```
<xsl:template match="PRODUCT_CODE[text() = 'BBB'][1]">
  <!-- Only matches the first time 'BBB' occurs -->
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If there do exist one or more `<PRODUCT_CODE>` elements with `'BBB'` text it matches *exactly* one time.

Comment: This was also helpful and illustrative to know/learn as well - Thank You.